# how to sort letters per their frequency in a word?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort letters in decreasing order of their frequency in a word. However if two letters have same frequency then alphabetically preceding letter should be picked.

I have used Counter to find the frequency of all the letters and it returns a dict. How can I sort them in decreasing order of their frequency and then select n number of letters with the highest frequency in alphabetical order

```
string='ddddaacccbb'
n=3
from collections import Counter
counter=Counter(string)
```

Suppose if the word is 'ddddaacccbb' and n is 3 then it should print ['a','c','d'], here n is number of letters. The output is based on highest frequency for each letter and if frequency is similar for two letters then alphabetically preceding one is selected.

Comment: So what is `n` for?

Comment: The word for those is "letters", not "alphabets".

Comment: If the order is by highest frequency, shouldn't it be `['d', 'c', 'a', 'b']` or  `['d', 'c', 'b', 'a]`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `most_common()` method of counters.

```
from collection import Counter
string = 'ddddaacccbb'
n = 3
count = Counter(string)
print([letter for letter, _ in count.most_common(n)])
```

Output will be

```
['d', 'c', 'a']
```

If you want alphabetical order on the output, you can sort the result.

```
print(sorted(letter for letter, _ in count.most_common(n)))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to retrieve the first n elements from the list via 
[Counter.most_common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) and extract out the letters, the sorting by most to least common is implicitly done by the `most_common` method

```
string='aacccbbdddd'
n=3
from collections import Counter
counter=Counter(string)

#Get the letters of n top values
res = [letter[0] for letter in counter.most_common(n)]
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
['d', 'c', 'a']
```

Comment: But that's not the output that this dude wants.

Comment: You are right, I corrected it @goodvibration please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` and retrieve a slice of the counter:

```
keys = sorted(counter, key=lambda x: (counter.get(x), x))
# sort by value, then key
result = keys[-n:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key= parameter of the sorted function:

For most...least frequent, with alphabetical order for same frequencies:

```
letters = sorted(counter,key=lambda c:(-counter[c],c))[:3]

# ['d', 'c', 'a']
```

For least...most frequent order, use this:

```
letters = sorted(counter,key=lambda c:(counter[c],c))[-3:]

# ['a', 'c', 'd']
```